# Angular2: loop dynamiccomponentloader to push each object in an array onto the dom?

Tags: angular

I'd like to roll an array of objects and use the properties from each index as input parameters of Angular2 components Id like to add to the dom

Bc these components are recursive, I need to use dynamiccomponentloader's function inside of a loop that traverses this array of objects (instead of *ngFor)

I am looking for an example that puts the component's template markup inside of a li (which is inside of a ul).

I am not certain how loadAsRoot, loadIntoLocation, or, loadNextToLocation can append a new li inside of a ul instead of just replacing its previous contents

I would be most grateful for a plnkr or fiddle to demonstrate this. Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Plunker example beta.17**](https://plnkr.co/edit/J4nj8d?p=preview)
[**Plunker example beta.9**](https://plnkr.co/edit/WaQs2R?p=preview)

```ts
import {Component, DynamicComponentLoader, ElementRef, Input} from 'angular2/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'dyn-cmp',
  template: `
  <h2>Dynamic {{name}}</h2>
`
})
export class DynCmp {
  @Input() name:string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  directives: [],
  template: `
  <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
  <div #target></div>
`
})
export class App {
  list = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
  constructor(private dcl:DynamicComponentLoader, private elRef:ElementRef) {
    this.name = 'Angular2';
  }  

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.list.forEach((val) => {
      this.dcl.loadIntoLocation(DynCmp, this.elRef, 'target')
      .then(cmpRef => cmpRef.instance.name = val);
    });
  }
}
```

You can't use `loadAsRoot()` because it removes the target and than can't be reused to add another component.

Comment: why are you not using this in your template property?

'Parent ( ... )'

Comment: Not sure what you mean. What should `Parent(...)` be or do?

Comment: I do not know what Parent(...) is supposed to do. I only ask because I see it on the Angular2 page and from your plnkr, it doesn't appear that you need it. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/DynamicComponentLoader-class.html    What is the purpose of Parent(...) ?

Comment: A bit late but anyway. `Parent` is just plain text in HTML to show something.

Comment: In that new Plunker example beta.17 that you posted, how would you perform cleanup if you invoked a function that looked like this?

pushD() { this.list.push('d'); )   or this popper() { this.list.pop(); }  

https://plnkr.co/edit/Nbfu7M?p=preview

Comment: The beta.17 example in http://stackoverflow.com/a/36325468/217408 shows how to dispose (`destory()` in beta.17) a dynamically created component. If you use such a wrapper you can use `ngOnDestroy()` to destroy the component when the wrapper is removed. Without the wrapper you would need to maintain a list of `cmpRef` to call `destroy()` on when you remove one from the list.

Comment: So if I am attempting to display a <ul> <li>...</li> <li ... </li>... </ul> inside of my parent view, I have two choices?(1) that each component represented in the <ul> ... </ul> will "self-destruct" (2) parent iterating over an array/object full of cmpRef references and invokes each element's cmpRef object's destroy() function

Comment: In your 17 example, a master parent instantiates the DCL wrapper with html tags. What kills(destroys) the DCL wrapped child component instance if the master parent itself uses DynamicCompnentLoader to instantiate its DCL wrapped child?

Comment: I don't get this part "if the master parent itself uses DynamicCompnentLoader to instantiate its DCL wrapped child?"

Comment: another way to say it - it looks like you've shown how to represent an individual view with DCL but how do you represent (and maintain) multiple components with DCL? Do you have a plnkr with this option: "maintain a list of cmpRef to call destroy() on when you remove one from the list" ?

Comment: for example, if I insert or delete at a particular index in my cmpRef array, or I .shuffle() the entire array, how is that change represented with the actual html dom elements? automatic change/rearrange?

Comment: The `<dcl-wrapper>` instances are normal components maintained by `*ngFor`. When `*ngFor` removes a component it calls `ngOnDestroy()` which calls `cmpRef.destory()`. Is that what you mean?

Comment: If you maintain `cmpRef` then you are fully responsible. You have to take care of everything yourself.